# Showing Javascript Syntax Error on runtime

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Getting Syntax error on runtime for the below script.

"SCRIPT1002: Syntax error"

Any help is much appreciated. !!!!

```
function changetext(s, e){
var cmbThemes=document.getElementById('cmbThemes');
var selectedValue = cmbThemes.options[cmbThemes.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedText = cmbThemes.options[cmbThemes.selectedIndex].text;
alert(selectedValue);
alert(selectedText);
if (selectedText() == "Glass"){
alert ("Glass");
}
}
```

Comment: There is no **syntax** error in the code you've posted, if you're getting that error it must be elsewhere. There *is* an error in that code, but not one that should result in anything saying "syntax error".

Comment: [SCRIPT1002: Syntax error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/shtk5xy2%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if (selectedText() == "Glass"){  **-->**   if (selectedText == "Glass"){  

selectedText() ---> selectedText
```

Remove `()` after selectedText

Comment: Hi, tried removing open and close parenthesis and that didn't turn up working.
Thanks any ways.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. The issue was really on the clientsideeditor of Devexpress i guess. 
It was not allowing more than 1 function in an event.

Thanks for your support anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved. 
Courtesy to the link below.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c5c6e2/populate-a-treeview-dynamically/